# Kitkat internal memory issue

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, internal-storage, sd-card

I am using HTC Desire 816 handset which contains 8 gb of internal memory.
In that 8gb i can use only 3.9gb for storing app related files and other stuffs,remaining space occupied by OS.
Currently i am facing memory not available issue while downloading through internet or installing new apps.
so i checked the space available in internal memory using ESS file explorer and
found 400mb space free and 3.5gb space used.
But i dont have that much files in my internal memory.
So i selected all the files in the **"emulated"** folder (**"0" & "Legacy"**) and checked the properties which shows total
size is 1.8gb.
Here my confusion is both the files are of size 1.8gb.But i select both the fiels and check the whole space it is showing 1.8gb only.
So where is the remaining space,which file occupying that space,can i delete that files.
please help me.

Comment: In your case, 0 and legacy both refer to the same location. If you want to save space, delete the *contents* of one of these